# Passing : in URL parameter for jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to fetch values from Envato using `jQuery.ajax()`, the URL parameter contains a colon which is not accepted by system.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var request=$.ajax(
        url: "https://api.envato.com/v1/market/random-new-files:themeforest.json",
        type: "GET",
        connection: "keep-alive",
        contentType: "application/json",
        mimeType: "application/json ",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer uO5xtTUXgJMyYPKg5fC9NNRGcue42QeD'
        }
    )}
    request.done(function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    })
```

This is the call, but I am getting error as per following screenshots: http://prntscr.com/b7poyo
http://prntscr.com/b7pp1b

Comment: unless you've miscopied some of the code above, the syntax looks out of whack to me.

Comment: Typo: The `$.ajax()` call is missing the opening `{` to start the `settings` object. The ending operators are also out-of-order – should be `})` on the line before `request.done(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some sintax errors

Try the following:

```
   $('button').click(function() {
     var request = $.ajax({
       url: "https://api.envato.com/v1/market/random-new-files:themeforest.json",
       type: "GET",
       connection: "keep-alive",
       contentType: "application/json",
       mimeType: "application/json ",
       headers: {
         "Authorization": 'Bearer uO5xtTUXgJMyYPKg5fC9NNRGcue42QeD'
       },
       success: function(data) {
         console.log(data)
       }
     })
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ukdh27r/

Comment: Damn it, I missed the syntax and was thinking there was some issue with url parameter itself. Silly me :p, thank you so much guys for your support. Stackoverflow is rising on my list to seek support for any issue. This is the best community :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the URL as follows:

```
url: "https://api.envato.com/v1/market/"+encodeURIComponent("random-new-files:themeforest.json")
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, that did not work, got same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this answer typed up, mostly finished by the time I noticed madalin's answer. It's basically the same code, but forgive me as I like to try and explain my answer a little.

First thing first: I have no idea what you did. Your Javascript in your question just immediately rang out to me as wrong. You had a lot of missing parenthesis and brackets. So, I started off by just making a very basic ajax call, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://api.envato.com/v1/market/random-new-files:themeforest.json"
 }).always(function(r) {
   console.log(r)
 });
```

I got an authentication error. I just copied over the rest of your `.ajax()` object and it worked just fine.

**Lesson for Next Time** Be careful about matching parenthesis and brackets.

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.envato.com/v1/market/random-new-files:themeforest.json',
    type: "GET",
    connection: "keep-alive",
    contentType: "application/json",
    mimeType: "application/json ",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": 'Bearer uO5xtTUXgJMyYPKg5fC9NNRGcue42QeD'
    }
  }).done(function(r) {
    console.log(r);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Sure Jhecht, will try be more careful in future regarding these parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error, `Unexpected token :`, is because JSONP is parsed as JavaScript, where `{...}` also represents blocks.

```
var callback = req.query.callback;
var data = JSON.stringify({
    Name : "Tom",
    Description : "Hello it's me!"
});

if (callback) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    res.end(callback + '(' + data + ')');
} else {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(data);
}
```

xpressJS also includes `res.jsonp()` that already implements this condition:

```
app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( 'req received' );

    res.jsonp({
        Name : "Tom",
        Description : "Hello it's me!"
    });
});
```